# Jenkins CI - SSL handshake_failure

Tags: java, ssl, hudson, jenkins

I am trying to configure Jenkins CI to perform continuous integration for our project and am unable to get it to connect to our SVN repository over https.  Any time I try to configure the repository URL and it attempts to connect I get the following exceptions:

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: OPTIONS /svn/repo/path failed
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:291)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:276)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:264)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:516)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:98)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1001)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.testConnection(DAVRepository.java:97)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.checkRepositoryPath(SubversionSCM.java:1966)
        at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doCheckRemote(SubversionSCM.java:1900)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:282)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:149)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:88)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:563)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:648)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:563)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:648)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:563)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:648)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:477)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:159)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
        at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
        at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:166)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:173)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at jenkins.security.ApiTokenFilter.doFilter(ApiTokenFilter.java:61)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
        at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:66)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
        at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
        at hudson.plugins.pwauth.PWauthFilter.doFilter(PWauthFilter.java:50)
        at hudson.plugins.pwauth.PWauthFilter.doFilter(PWauthFilter.java:37)
        at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: OPTIONS /svn/repo/path failed
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:146)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:89)
        ... 81 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/repo/path'
svn: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:644)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:285)
        ... 80 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/repo/path'
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:642)
        ... 81 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:101)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:389)
        ... 81 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.sendData(HTTPConnection.java:229)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:166)
        at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:364)
    ... 81 more
```

I enabled SSL debugging on my tomcat instance (using `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake`) and got the following:

```
X509KeyManager passed to SSLContext.init():  need an X509ExtendedKeyManager for SSLEngine use
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Handling GET /jenkins/job/projectName/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM/checkRemote : TP-Processor3, setSoTimeout(3600000) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, SSLv3
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1330544609 bytes = { 141, 119, 147, 122, 40, 183, 52, 147, 58, 49, 199, 147, 190, 160, 8, 252, 253, 194, 196, 96, 220, 88, 240, 200, 69, 210, 123, 127 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
***
Handling GET /jenkins/job/projectName/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM/checkRemote : TP-Processor3, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 163
Handling GET /jenkins/job/projectName/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM/checkRemote : TP-Processor3, READ: SSLv3 Alert, length = 2
Handling GET /jenkins/job/projectName/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM/checkRemote : TP-Processor3, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
Handling GET /jenkins/job/projectName/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM/checkRemote : TP-Processor3, called closeSocket()
Handling GET /jenkins/job/projectName/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM/checkRemote : TP-Processor3, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Handling GET /jenkins/job/projectName/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM/checkRemote : TP-Processor3, called close()
Handling GET /jenkins/job/projectName/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM/checkRemote : TP-Processor3, called closeInternal(true)
Handling GET /jenkins/job/projectName/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM/checkRemote : TP-Processor3, called close()
Handling GET /jenkins/job/projectName/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM/checkRemote : TP-Processor3, called closeInternal(true)
```

I tried adding the `-Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3` property in my tomcat as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159586/jsse-handshake-failure-on-public-https-web-site) post and still had the same error.

At this point I'm completely stumped as to what is going on... unfortunately I'm no SSL expert to fully understand the SSL debug information.  Anyone have any thoughts on how to correct this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it looks like it was an issue dealing with the SSL configuration on the server.  Apparently SVNKit won't work with TLSv1 for some reason.

Our initial configuration was to only allow TLSv1:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1
```

So, the fix was to enable TLSv1 and SSLv3:

```
SSLProtocol -all +SSLv3 +TLSv1
```

Comment: how do you configure svnkit?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server is responding back to the client, but the client doesn't like the response. Look at the client side log and see if there is anything that will hint what the problem might be.

Comment: This is from the 'client' side.  The SSL client is a tomcat application (Jenkins) that is calling our SVN (httpd) server.

Comment: And the SVN httpd log doesn't have any data as to the failure? What is strange is that tomcat is sending extensions with SSLv3, where it probably shouldn't. Try disabling the ECC ciphersuites, which will remove the need for the extensions, because your server might be misbehaving on them. Alternatively, try enabling TLS 1.0.