# How to set SSL protocol in Hudson

Tags: tomcat, svn, ssl, hudson

I'm using Hudson to build application's war file. Source code is accessed via Tortoise SVN. Hudson is running on Tomcat.
Recently in our company it was decided to disable SSLv3 protocol and since then I can't build war file.
Apparently it can't access SVN. The exception is:

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: OPTIONS /BY/CU-0747%20(Web%20Ecado)/branches/Nuvola_1.9.1 failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:279)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:267)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:516)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:98)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1002)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.testConnection(DAVRepository.java:98)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.checkRepositoryPath(SubversionSCM.java:1954)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doCheckRemote(SubversionSCM.java:1885)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:282)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:88)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:103)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:561)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:646)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:233)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:561)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:646)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:233)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:561)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:646)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:477)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:159)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:94)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:180)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:148)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:97)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:180)
    at org.hudsonci.servlets.internal.ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.doFilter(ServletRegistrationFilterAdapter.java:148)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:97)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:166)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilter(BasicProcessingFilter.java:173)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:66)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: OPTIONS /BY/CU-0747%20(Web%20Ecado)/branches/Nuvola_1.9.1 failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:146)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:89)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/BY/CU-0747%20(Web%20Ecado)/branches/Nuvola_1.9.1'
svn: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:655)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:288)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/BY/CU-0747%20(Web%20Ecado)/branches/Nuvola_1.9.1'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:200)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:653)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage: svn: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:101)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:400)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1682)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:932)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1112)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:623)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:59)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.sendData(HTTPConnection.java:231)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPRequest.dispatch(HTTPRequest.java:168)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:372)
    ... 80 more
```

I've tried setting `Dhttps.protocols` and `svnkit.http.sslProtocols` properties in Tomcat as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519248/jenkins-ci-ssl-handshake-failure), but it did not work.
Also I was looking for details of hudson configuration for SVN and the best I found is [this](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ch09.html), but there are no inner details on how Hudson works with SVN.

Obviously I can build war file using command line command, but I think there must be a place somewhere in hudson where I can configure SSL protocol. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was version conflict between Hudson and SVN. After update of Hudson everything works as expected.